# ObjectListView permit vertical scrolling even when control is disabled?

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollbar, objectlistview

In an ObjectListView (or one of its variants like DataListView) is there a way to permit vertical scrolling even when control is disabled?

Currently, disabling the control stops the vertical scrollbar from responding to mouse activity.

Answer (score 0):

According to:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.enabled?view=netframework-4.8

> Control.Enabled Property
>
> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the control can respond to
> user interaction.

So by disabling the control then you remove all user interaction, which includes scrolling.  As this is inherited by all Controls then ObjectListView works the same way.

So you don't want to disable to the control.

It is not clear exactly what you want to achieve, but ObjectListView does have a way to disable some (or all) of the Objects that you set.

An example:
Let's say you have a simple Class of Telephone numbers, which also includes an IsValid method.

```
 public class TelephoneNumber
 {
      public string Number { get; set; }
      public string Owner { get; set; }
      public string City { get; set; }

      public bool IsValid()
      {
          //code to check if number is valid
          if (this.Number.Length > 5)
              return true;
          else
              return false;
      }
 }
```

You populate the list and set your ObjectListView list of Objects as normal.

```
List<TelephoneNumber> MyNumbers = new List<TelephoneNumber>();
MyNumbers.Add(new TelephoneNumber() { Number = "9512636272", City = "London", Owner = "Bob's Grill" });
MyNumbers.Add(new TelephoneNumber() { Number = "9518263729", City = "Frankfurt am Main", Owner = "Tagesschau" });
MyNumbers.Add(new TelephoneNumber() { Number = "951", City = "Wiesbaden",  Owner = "John"});

this.objectListView1.SetObjects(MyNumbers);
```

Then to set some of these objects to be disabled you generate a new sub-list and use set these as disabled.

```
//Generate new list of Incorrect numbers
List<TelephoneNumber> Incorrect = MyNumbers.FindAll(delegate (TelephoneNumber number) { return !number.IsValid(); });
//Set these to be Disabled
this.objectListView1.DisabledObjects = Incorrect;
```

There are methods to Disable and Enable a single or multiple objects or the whole list of objects.

See the documentation for more details.  Scroll towards the bottom for more details how to do this.
http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/blog8.html